# Any ideas? Mouseenter/Mouseleave (I'm stuck)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on my "very own project" in the end of the jQuery course at code academy but I'm stuck for now.

**Here is my js/jQ code:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.Left1').click(function () {
        $('.content1').slideToggle('slow');
    });
    $('.PilLine1').mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).fadeTo(500, 1);
    });
    $('.PileLine1').mouseleave(function () {
        if ($('.content1').show('false')) {
            $('.PileLine1').fadeTo(500, 0.3);
        }
        else$('.PileLine1').fadeTo(500, 1);
    });
});
```

**And here is a visual preview:**
http://www.codecademy.com/users/5155e412f38e624ec7000116/projects/500c7558d143430002002551

Okey, well It doesn't work out as I want it to. I want my if/else statement to check **if** my box(content1) is visible or not. **If** it's visible And mouseleave; I want my PilLine1 to stay at a opacity with 100%. **if else** mouseleave and closed; I want my PilLine1 to fade out to a opacity with 30%.

**Should i use:** `if($('.content1').show('false'))` or `if($('.content1').css('display'==='none'))`
or am I completely lost?

Comment: `if($('.content1').is(':visible')`

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, why not post this as an answer?

Comment: @ASGM I don't know, sometimes I'm all over the place and just make comments and let other people benefit from that sweet, sweet karma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery's `.is()` wlil *check the current matched set of elements against a selector, element, or jQuery object and return true if at least one of these elements matches the given arguments.*

```
if($('.content1').is(':visible'))
```

the `:visible:` method will check for `display: none`, if not `display:none` it returns true.

This can be problematic when leveraging opacity or visibility, however

*Elements with visibility: hidden or opacity: 0 are considered visible, since they still consume space in the layout. During animations that hide an element, the element is considered to be visible until the end of the animation. During animations to show an element, the element is considered to be visible at the start at the animation.*